# Google pay payment using token

Tags: binance

Can I use my token (BSC TOKEN) to pay on Google pay or any services which uses QRCode to receive payment.? Can anyone please share some links or code.?

Answer (score 0):

No, The service needs to have a blockchain wallet, which they do not right now.

Comment: I have seen someone uses such a service.  They have android app which shows the balance of their token and if user wish to pay on any qr code service like Google Pay or PayTM, he can scan and pay through token balance.

Comment: That is just available in certain countries. Some examples are Binance Pay, Bitpay and Foldapp. But these are external apps that provides this service, it is not you sending crypto directly to a supplier.

Comment: Can you share some links with me

Comment: Fold app - https://foldapp.com/
Bitpay - https://bitpay.com/
Binance pay - https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/d6fabc736d1f4e7fb60e56afe6d1f3b9